# IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable

Tags: entity-framework

The question was originally asked at http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/399499#post928179 .

Good day! Please tell me if it is wrong place to post this question.

I have a query as follows:

```
IQueryable<Card> cardsQuery =
  dataContext.Cards
  .Where(predicate)
  .OrderByDescending(kc => kc.SendDate)
  .AsQueryable();
```

Then I try:

`Task<Card[]> result = cardsQuery.ToArrayAsync();`

And then exception rises:

`The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable<Models.Card>`

I use modified version of 'EF 5.x DbCotext generator'.

How to avoid it?

**UPDATE**

Important remark is that I have method to produce `IQuerayble<Card>` as follows:

```
class Repository {
  public IQueryable<Card> GetKudosCards(Func<Card, bool> predicate) {
    IEnumerable<KudosCard> kudosCards = kudosCardsQuery.Where(predicate);
     return kudosCards
            .OrderByDescending(kc => kc.SendDate)
            .AsQueryable();
  }
}
```

Comment: Arthur (at http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/399499#post928179) is right. There is another operation between IQueryable<> and ToArrayAsync. It is ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo from OData package. It materializes IQueryable according to OData parameters of HTTP-request. So, my code is sync while ApplyTo is sync, right?

Comment: I think you getting this when you trying to write a test. If you don't want to change your production code follow the steps here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx#async

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is as follows.

I have a method:

```
class Repository {
  public IQueryable<Card> GetKudosCards(Func<Card, bool> predicate) {
    IEnumerable<KudosCard> kudosCards = kudosCardsQuery.Where(predicate);
    return kudosCards
            .OrderByDescending(kc => kc.SendDate)
            .AsQueryable();
  }
}
```

The problem is that kudosCards has type `IEnumerable<KudosCard>`. That throws exception. If I change predicate type to `Expression<Func<Card, bool> predicate` then everything works just fine.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem when I was using the LinqKit library expression builder, which in the end, was producing `AsQueryable()`, and very surprisingly it was happening for me from the XUnit Integration Tests call.

I was going wild about why the same problem wasn't happening when calling the same API endpoint via Swagger.

It turned out I had to do an elementary change.
I had to replace:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

with:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Answer (score 9):

What is the point of calling AsQueryable? If you compose a query with the extension methods starting from an IQueryable source collection (e.g. DbSet, ObjectSet), the query will be IQueryable too.

The purpose of AsQueryable is to wrap an IEnumerable collection with an IQueryable proxy/adapter that uses a Linq provider that is capable of compiling IQueryable queries into a Linq to Object queries. This can be useful in scenarios when you would like to use inmemory data queries.

Why is the AsQueryable call necessary? What if you just simply remove it?

**Update**

Okey, now it seems I understand your problem. After a quick look on the [ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b11acf178a83#src/System.Web.Http.OData/OData/Query/ODataQueryOptions.cs) I realized that it just extends the underlying expression tree of the query. You can still use it to run the query in the way you want, however you need a little trick to transform the query back to generic.

```
IQueryable<Card> cardsQuery =
   dataContext.Cards
    .Where(predicate)
    .OrderByDescending(kc => kc.SendDate);


IQueryable odataQuery = queryOptions.ApplyTo(cardsQuery);

// The OData query option applier creates a non generic query, transform it back to generic
cardsQuery = cardsQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<Card>(odataQuery.Expression);

Task<Card[]> result = cardsQuery.ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: Seems like you're right. I can remove AsQueryable and explicitly cast OrderByDescending(...) to IQueryable<Card>. Still, this isn't a problem. The problem is that I need async request to database. Should I simply wrap ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo to Task.Factory.StartNew? I don't think it is a good decision since db-request will be blocking.

Comment: my kudos for a tricky method! You are right saying that IQueryable materialization occurs when ToArray(Async) called but no while queryOptions.ApplyTo. Still, your approach doesn't work. I have the same error: The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable<Card>. cardsQuery has type {System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[Card,System.DateTime]}.

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts! The problem was in another place. I would vote up your answer when I have 15 of reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was using the [LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit.EntityFramework/) library expression builder, which in the end, was producing `AsQueryable()`.
And very surprisingly, it was happening for me from the **XUnit** Integration Tests call.

I was going wild about why the same problem wasn't happening when calling the same API endpoint via Swagger.

---

It turned out I had to do an elementary change.
I had to replace the:

```cs
using System.Data.Entity;
```

with:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

In the place where I was calling the [LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit.EntityFramework/) expression method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `List<T>` for Linq query, Avoid chaining it with ToListAsync(). It uses the class IDbAsyncEnumerable that is not available to a normal `List<T>` object